# Парсинг текста в квадратных и обычных скобках

Tags: python, текст

Задача вывести текст из, допустим такой строки - "[текст1] (текст2)". Проблема усложняется тем, что таких строк много написанных через азбац. Ниже пример того, что я хочу спарсить и какой результат получить на выходе.

['строка1'] ('текст1')

['строка2'] ('текст2')

['строка3'] ('текст3')

Где на выходе хочу получить многомерный список вида

`parsed = ['строка1', 'текст1'], ['строка2', 'текст2'], ['строка3','текст3']`

Comment: и даже совсем нет никаких собственных идей?

Comment: @Эникейщик был бы рад

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно где то так

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re

# здесь спрятана вся магия. Не пытайтесь это прочитать, можно что то вызывать
regex = r"(\['([^]]+)'\]|\('([^)]+)'\))"
r = []
f = open("data.txt")
# читаем файл построчно
for l in f:
    # тут будет улов с текущей строки
    sb = []
    matches = re.findall(regex, l)
    # если ничего не нашли - то и делать нечего
    if len(matches) == 0:
        continue
    # по всем найденным кусочкам смотрим
    for x in matches:
        # у нас там два варианта, поэтому проверяем, где зарылся бегемот
        if (x[1] == ''):
            sb.append(x[2])
        else:
            sb.append(x[1])
    # и добавляем найденный массив в больший
    r.append(sb)
# осталось по мелочам - распечатать это все дело.
print(r)
```

Если же строки файла содержат только указанные в примере варианты (там по две строки), то все можно сильно-сильно упростить

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re

regex = r"(\['([^]]+)'\]\s*\('([^)]+)'\))"
r = []
f = open("data.txt")
for l in f:
    matches = re.findall(regex, l)
    if len(matches) == 0 or len(matches[0]) != 3:
        continue
    r.append([matches[0][1], matches[0][2]])
print(r)
```

Некоторые люди могут предлагать использовать "питоник-вей", но он хорош для "однократных задач".

Answer (score 1):

у *KoVadim* какой-то сложный ответ выше вышел. Как мне кажется, можно немного проще спарсить.

```
import re

text = """['строка1'] ('текст1')
['строка2'] ('текст2')
['строка3'] ('текст3')"""

parsed = list(map(list, re.findall("\['(\w+)'\]\s+\('(\w+)'\)", text)))
```

Comment: немного не то на выходе, тут просят список списков, а не кортежей

Comment: он не сложен (хотя его можно упростить, сильно). я просто детально. плюс автор написал " у меня таких строк много." и я решил, что может быть имеется ввиду "[текст1] (текст2) [текст3] (текст4)" и так далее.

Comment: @Эникейщик Поправил) Хотя не думаю, что этот момент принципиален.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re
txt = """['строка1'] ('текст1')
['строка2'] ('текст2')
['строка3'] ('текст3')"""

data = re.findall(r"(?<=[\[(]').+?(?='[)\]])", txt, flags=re.S)
print(
    *map(list, zip(data[::2], data[1::2]))
)
# ['строка1', 'текст1'] ['строка2', 'текст2'] ['строка3', 'текст3']

print(
    list(map(list, zip(data[::2], data[1::2])))
)
# [['строка1', 'текст1'], ['строка2', 'текст2'], ['строка3', 'текст3']]

print(
    dict(zip(data[::2], data[1::2]))
)
# {'строка1': 'текст1', 'строка2': 'текст2', 'строка3': 'текст3'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Лёгкий способ

```
s = '''\
['строка1'] ('текст1')

['строка2'] ('текст2')

['строка3'] ('текст3')
'''

l = [[eval(i.split()[0])[0], eval(i.split()[1])] for i in s.split('\n') if i]
print(l)

# [['строка1', 'текст1'], ['строка2', 'текст2'], ['строка3', 'текст3']]
```